# foreach с присвоением ";"

Tags: php, циклы

Добрый день.

В цикле `foreach` я добавляю к каждому id ";".
После операции у меня получается результат `1;2;3;4;5;6;`.
Как избавится от добавления ";" после последнего элемента?
Т.е., чтобы в итоге получилось `1;2;3;4;5;6`

```
$id_product = "";

foreach($cart as $item){
    $id_product.= $item["id"].";";
}
```

Comment: поставил плюсик всем implode-кунам

Comment: Круто. Вы сделали мне вечер.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$myarr = array();

foreach ($cart as $item) {
    $myarr[]=$item['id'];
}
$id_product = implode(";", $myarr);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
trim($id_product, ';');
```

Comment: Элегантное решение.

Answer (score 5):

Еще-еще-еще!

```
$id_product = array();

array_map(function($item) use (&$id_product){
    $ids[] = $item['id'];
}, $cart);

$id_product = implode(';', $ids);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$id_product = "";

foreach($cart as $item){
        $id_product.= $item["id"].";";
}
$id_product = substr($id_product,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array();

foreach ($cart as $item){   
   $array[] = $item['id'];  
}

if(count($array) > 0)    
   $new_array = implode(";",$array);
```

Comment: Тут в $array[] = $item ключ ("id") потерян.

Comment: спасибо поправил

Comment: хотя суть не в этом :)

Answer (score 2):

После цикла проверить - если последний знак ";", то удалить его

Answer (score 2):

Ну и я поучаствую в этом шоу. Разовью идею [[@ErrorMan](/users/9185/errorman)](/users/9185/errorman) и нагорожу свой огород:

```
$id_product = '';

for ($x = 0; $x < count($cart); $x++) {
  $id_product .= $cart[$x]['id'];
  if ($x != count($cart) -1)
    $id_product .= ';';
}
```

То же, но с foreach():

```
$id_product = '';
$x = 1;

foreach ($cart as $i) {
  $id_product .= $i['id'];
  if ($x != count($cart))
    $id_product .= ';';
  $x++;
}
```

Хотя решение с implode() предпочтительнее. См. выше.

Answer (score -2):

```
$count = count($cart);
$id_product = "";
$i=0
foreach($cart as $item){
$i++;
if($i!=$count){
    $id_product.= $item["id"].";";
}

    else{
    $id_product.= $item["id"];
}

}
```

что-то вроде этого